# Can I sell my art with living beings on it which I made in a time I didn't know it wasn't halal?

Tags: drawing, art

In the past, I used to draw a lot of Anime characters and living beings, but now, Alhamdulillah, I have stopped that because I know that it is not permissible.

Can I sell my art with living beings on it, since its not something I would like to throw away? If I do so, would I make a sin for providing others with such pictures to hang in their rooms, where no angels come?

If it is a sin to sell something like that, Ii would definitely burn them. I just need an evidence hadith or Quran verse where it says that.

Answer (score 0):

Salam, sorry this is late. But wanted to shed some light. So you cannot sell or earn anything from it as you are trying to earn from something that is Haram. Just like how we can't consume alcohol and pig meat, we are also not allowed to earn from selling those items. You should burn them away. Jzk

Comment: Alaykumussalam. Thank you for your answer! Uuf this was long ago. I‘m not sure anymore if I burned them away or just threw them in the paper bin, but I have no Haram artwork in my house anymore, Alhamdulillah. If I draw living creatures, then with no eyes, but with nose and mouth.

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
In my opinion, I don't think it is haram to sell your artwork. As long as the buyers are not workshipping the work, there should be no issues. I think what is haram is creating idols for sale. That is totally different. Hope that helps. :)
-Michelle

Comment: Salaam sister, It is good that you posted your opinion by clearly stating that it is your opinion. However, when posting opinions it is better to include the basis on which this opinion was formed.